# Receiving only different values from serial port

Tags: c#

I have a project like a registration system using RFID. When user enabled registration mode, each card shown should be saved only once. For this, I am using an array and then checking the same code in array to see if it exists already. But I have a problem with incrementing the array index.

in class Form1, i have the initializations:

```
string rx_data = "";
string last_data = "";
string[] availablePlayers = {""};
int plIndex = 0;
```

In the code below, if I use `plIndex`, it receives only the first card and seems like it stops calling this handler again.

```
    public void WriteRxData(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (connection.IsOpen && !cardSaveCon.IsOpen)
        {
            try
            {
                rx_data = connection.ReadLine(); // check how the data ends
               if (!availablePlayers.Any(rx_data.Contains))
                {
                    availablePlayers[plIndex] = rx_data;
                    receivedData.AppendText(rx_data);
                    plIndex++;
                }

            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
```

But instead,  If I use a hardcoded index value, it works. I would like to know how to handle this since this had to work for other languages. I am new to c#, so there may be some parts that I am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  availablePlayers[plIndex] = rx_data;
```

This will crash your code the second time you receive a string.  Unfortunately you are also catching the IndexOutOfRangeException and close the port.  Which will completely deadlock the code, SerialPort.Close() can only complete when the event handler has returned.

Specific counter-measures:

- use a `List<string>` instead of a string[]
- remove try/catch from your code, it cannot ever do anything but make your program fail without a way to recover
- write an event handler for AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException to provide a diagnostic when your program dies on unexpected exceptions
- get familiar with the Debug + Windows + Threads debugger window.  It allows you to see what's going on in other threads, you would have seen the deadlock.

Comment: Compliments for the question btw, you documented it well and made it easy to help you.

Comment: Thanks for help, but I couldnt understand why it complains about OutOfRange here `savedCards.AppendText(last_data+ "=\n");`

Comment: It doesn't.  As I recommended, remove try/catch to see where the exception is thrown.  You should then also see the problem with the  availablePlayers array.  Which has *one* element, so trying to set the 2nd element is going to go klaboom!